# Automating windows server 2008 installation in hyper V with powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, powershell, installation, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I often set up servers in Hyper V on my laptop (running windows server 2008) to test varoius software.

Is there a way in powershell to build an image in Hyper V and run windows update on that image? Does anyone have a script that they could share?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a WIM image of the virtualized operating system, and run offline updates against it with DISM.

See here for more information: http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2012/02/15/applying-windows-updates-to-a-base-wim-using-dism-and-powershell.aspx

Comment: You can do the same without making a WIM image first.  Just run the offline update against the image in the VHD, by mounting the VHD.